# What is the difference between a custom default constructor and defaulted default constructor in C++

Tags: c++

I am working on a program that behaves differently when I set the default constructor to when I omit it. Specifically I am building an object to pass it to a third-party library function. When I omit the default constructor, the function works as expected, however when I define it the function blocks and does not return control, so I think the problem is due to the constructor.

Below I show a summary excerpt of the part of the code that has to do with the problem.

```
class Config {
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Config> SPtr;

    int frame;
    int numSolidParticles = 0;
    bool shapesChanged = false;

    Buffer* buffer;
    FlexParams params;  // struct

    // if omitted then the 3rd party method works as expected
    Config() {
    }
};

...

Config::SPtr config = std::make_shared<Config>();

initialize(config);

...
SetFlexParams(config->params);
// calls to other 3rd party methods that depends on config
...

// call 3rd party library's method that causes the issue
mapBuffer(config->buffer);
```

**Update**: What I'm trying to do is moving some of the initializations (e.g. `frame`, `buffer` and other fields not shown) in method `inititalize` to constructor.

Comment: What do you mean by that it "behaves differently"? Any error? Please add the prototype of the third-party function being called in this context.

Comment: I mean this "when I omit the default constructor, the function works as expected, however when I define it the function blocks and does not return control".

Comment: Can you tell more about the third party method. Your class Config, inherits no interface, which makes me suspecious about how this method api  thirdPartyMethod() is supposed to interact with Config objects?

Comment: It seems to me that the issue is: how is the default constructor as given explicitly in the code example different from the default constructor that would be implicitly declared if no default constructor was provided? The answer to that question isn't obvious to me as yet, but I'm not a C++ code lawyer ...

Comment: Is there anything mentioned about the passed pointer in that library documentation? Something about the state of the argument being passed? The class Config contains four (4) data members i.e. `frame`, `numSolidParticles`, `shapesChanged` and `buffer`; so is it safe to assume that these are required by that library function, right?

Comment: @kishoredbn you are right, I simplified too much. What it is passed to  `thirdPartyMethod` is a pointer to a `Buffer` object, which is a class of the third party library.

Comment: @Simon that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: I updated the question to give a little more details

Comment: @JoseD.Rodriguez Now you are actually working with (not `Buffer` objects) but pointer to `Buffer` objects. But you are not allocating any memory nor initializing that in your constructor. How is it supposed to work? I was the creator of `mapBuffer()` method, first think I would done is check for null arguments and simply return if it was so.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain correctly but the `buffer` pointer is initialized in the `initialize()` method. I think key here is the constructor, just be removing it everything works.

Comment: I think you may have to show the definition of `initialize()` as well, in case something weird is going on there.

Comment: @JoseD.Rodriguez even if say you are initializing in the `initialize()` function, where are you initializing things? You need to have some memory. At least `*buffer = new Buffer()` in the constructor.

Comment: The obvious difference between a "defaulted" constructor and a manually implemented one, will be in how it initialises members of the class. For example, whether `buffer` is initialised to a `nullptr` (so accessing its value - to, say, compare with `nullptr` - is fine but dereferencing causes undefined behaviour) versus being left uninitialised (in which case, accessing its value - even if it is not dereferenced - causes undefined behaviour).  Without a [mcve] which shows how your class and constructors are actually defined, and what your `initialize()` function does, nobody can help.

Comment: I've written two hypothetical short programs containing the `Config` class as defined here, that differed only in the presence or absence of the explicit constructor. Both included a simple `initialize()` function. I compiled both with ` g++ -O0 -S` to produce assembler (.s) files. The assembler files did indeed turn out to be different between the two versions. Since my code isn't your code, that doesn't help you much but, if you used the same approach with your code that might tell you what the compiler is doing differently between the versions with the explicit and implicit constructors.

Comment: I agree with @Peter. This smells like UB somewhere in either your code or (hopefully not) the 3rd party's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between a custom default constructor and
>   defaulted default constructor?

Given a class `X`, if: ([[class.ctor]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.ctor#5))

> - `X` is a union that has a variant member with a non-trivial default constructor and no variant member of `X` has a default member
>     initializer,
> - `X` is a non-union class that has a variant member M with a non-trivial default constructor and no variant member of the anonymous
>     union containing M has a default member initializer,
> - any non-static data member with no default member initializer is of reference type,
> - any non-variant non-static data member of const-qualified type (or array thereof) with no *brace-or-equal-initializer* does not have a
>     user-provided default constructor,
> - `X` is a union and all of its variant members are of const-qualified type (or array thereof),
> - `X` is a non-union class and all members of any anonymous union member are of const-qualified type (or array thereof),
> - any potentially constructed subobject, except for a non-static data member with a *brace-or-equal-initializer*, has class type `M`
>     (or array thereof) and either `M` has no default constructor or
>     overload resolution as applied to find `M`'s corresponding constructor
>     results in an ambiguity or in a function that is deleted or
>     inaccessible from the defaulted default constructor, or
> - any potentially constructed subobject has a type with a destructor that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted default
>     constructor.

then the defaulted default constructor of `X` is defined as deleted, whereas a hand-written `X() {}` will be ill-formed.

Otherwise, there is no difference.

Comment: I don't believe this addresses the question.   It lists the circumstances in which a default destructor is deleted, and a hand-written version makes the program ill-formed.      It doesn't describe, when a defaulted default constructor is allowed, what the defaulted constructor does, or how what may differ from a hand-rolled one.

Comment: @Peter I did, "Otherwise, there is no difference."

Answer (score 0):

Although this does not answer the main question I would like to explain that the problem was being caused by a field of the `FlexParams` struct that I was forgetting to initialize.

This struct groups a large number of parameters to 3rd party library that are initialized in the `initialize` function. The funny thing is that when I do not define the constructor the field is initialized to 0 (which luckily was the correct value) while when I define it the field takes a random value.

The only reasonable explanation, as some of you mentioned in the comments, is that the issue was caused by undefined behavior.

Comment: what happens if you have this line in the class's body: `FlexParams params{};`? This will cause the default initialization regardless of whether you remember to do so in your constructor (same goes for an `int frame{0};` and a `Buffer* buffer{nullptr};` in the same code)

Answer (score 0):

Default default constructor does one thing your manual default constructor does not: it properly default-constructs the members. I'm pretty sure that if you do either of the following your code will magically start working:

Option 1: Explicitly state default values for all the members (not just the two you have done so for)

```
int frame = 0;
int numSolidParticles = 0;
bool shapesChanged = false;

Buffer* buffer = nullptr;
FlexParams params = {};  // struct
```

Option 2: Remember to initialize all non-trivially-constructible members in your constructor

```
Config()
  : frame{0}
  , numSolidParticles{0}
  , shapesChanged{false}
  , buffer{nullptr}
  , params{} // I think this is the code generated by your compiler for the default default constructor
{
}
```

I personally prefer the first approach as it is clearer and way less prone to errors in a long run